# Centered resizing images css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So, I got a slide with images inside a div, and when i resize it they anchor the top left of the image. Is there any way to make it resize from the center of the image without using it as background ?

```
.fulls{
  width:100%; 
  height:100%;
  min-height: 1200px;
  min-width: 1900px;
}
```

This is the format im using for the images.

This is the web the example on the home [link](http://costa.io/pruebas/index.html)

Thanks

Comment: can you post the link of your site?

Comment: I cant.. work issues but ill try to upload something to show

Comment: debug it using inspect element.

Comment: The div by wich the image is in. Add this `<div style="text-align:center" >`

Comment: `wrapper` of image-gallery should have `margin: 0 auto` property..

Comment: @David It's probably best that you don't include a link in your question as the question itself should have a reproducible example. A Stack Snippet would be perfect. If you provide a link to an external site and the site disappears/problem gets fixed then the question will be of little use to other users. That said, what you are after should be possible: https://jsfiddle.net/qpq4376j/. Is this the sort of thing you are after?

Comment: Ok this is the web [link](http://costa.io/pruebas/) ,  the index is the one with the problem.

Comment: I tried with margin 0 auto and text-align:center and didnt work, same with   justify-content: center

Comment: Not working either removing the height:100%

Comment: Another thing you have restricted your images to   min-height: 1200px;
  min-width: 1900px; that one will make the images less responsive. you have already stated width to 100% and height to 100%.. so it cant be as responsive to smaller screens

Comment: Ye i agree with you. To be honest those min-height and min-width are just tryouts, just looking for something like [link](http://vegas.jaysalvat.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to center your image within it's container.

Adding left/top and transform properties to the image will keep the image centered.

```
.fulls {
    height: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    min-height: 1200px;
    min-width: 1900px;
    position: relative;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%); // ADD VENDOR PREFIXES TO THIS PROPERTY
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Yeah! Working perfectly, i can remove now the min-height and min-width, working perfectly. Thanks everyone

Comment: Cool, if you could mark the answer as correct when you get a chance then please.

Comment: Ok i had a problem now, not rly important but i ask anyway.

With resolutions like 1000x500 (ye its kinda weird resolution) the image resize dont work properly and show blank spaces on sides. Is there any way to fix it ?? If not dont worry

I fix it putting again the min width but dont know if thats a good way to fix it

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing something like:

HTML

```
<div class="slideshow">
    <img class="slide" src="..." />
    <img class="slide" src="..." />
</div>
```

CSS

```
.slideshow {
    width: 100%; // or amount of pixels, what you choose
    height: 100%; // gets height of parent div, or choose amount of pixels
}

.slide {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Watch out for strange image proportions though. When making a child element 100% width and height, it inherits the properties from the parent element. This makes it cover the entire slideshow. Is this what you want?

Here's a jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/Ber_4B/r1t53uub/

Comment: Yes, i want to make it stay on the whole screen when u enter the web. Its to achieve something like this resize [link](http://vegas.jaysalvat.com/)

Comment: You should give the slideshow div a height of 100vh then.

Comment: I tried that and didnt work but then i tried what Aaron said and worked perfectly, thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

I'll go with this kind of aproach

HTML

```
<div class="slideshow">
   <div class="slide" style="background-image:url('.../..');></div>
   <div class="slide" style="background-image:url('.../..');></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.slideshow {...}
.slide {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background-position:center;
    background-size:cover;
}
```